Azure portal not showing Azure functions
When I deploy the Azure Function project from VSCode to a new Function App, I get the Create Function App "name" Succeeded notification.

However, Funtion is not visible in both the VSCode directory and Azure Portal.


Function Code:
import azure.functions as func
import logging

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)

@app.route(route="http_trigger")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )


Please provide your function code.

Did you get the option to deploy after creation of the function?

Hi @PravallikaKV, function code added

Right on your function and select Deploy to function app, then you will get an option to deploy the function. Refer Image.


As per the screenshot, I can see the function app is created and the deployment is not done yet.
Right click on your newly created function app and select Deploy to Function App.



It displays the below dialogue with Deploy option.



Once the Deploy option is selected, it starts the deployment.

Deployment status:

Refresh the Resources and check the deployed functions in your function app.


I have deployed your function code to Azure function app and working as expected.

Portal:


